# How to prevent the character '\' from escaping ES6 template strings?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

In ES6, I can do something like this:

```
let myString = `My var: ${myVar}`;
```

That will automatically replace `${myVar}` with the actual value of `myVar`. Perfect.

But what if I have something like this?

```
let myString = `My var: \${myVar}`;
```

The character `\` is escaping the `${}` construct. It just becomes a regular string.

How can I make `\` **not to escape** in this case?

Comment: Why do you have a `\\` char there?

Comment: I have it there because I'm dynamically building a Regex

Comment: So you should probably fix the regex.

Comment: The Regex I'm dynamically building needs the backslash.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want `myVar` substituted in the final output? If so, why are you putting the slash between the `$` and `{`? If you don't, why are you using template strings?

Comment: If you were to manually write out the result you want in a standard JS string, what would it be?

Comment: @andrerpena: please show us your actual use case. Seems likely that you want `"\\${myVar}"` or something like that, but we can't tell without you showing your actual code.

Comment: double escaping is the answer... "\\${myVar}". Now you can figure out what I wanted. I answered my own question but I deleted it to give you the chance to answer, if you do, I'll accept it.

Comment: @andrerpena: What confused us all so much is that you put the backslash between the `$` and the `{`…

Comment: @Bergi... aaaaaaahh fu**. I'm so sorry for that... :( Bergi.. please answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to have a literal backslash in your template string, you will need to escape it:

```
let myVar = "test";
let myString = `My var: \\${myVar}`; // "My var: \test"
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the typo.. I edited the question.

Comment: Just tried the above with Node.js - versions v4.3.1 and v.7.5.0 and answer suggested above does not work. The output is 'My var: \\test'

Comment: Seems to relate to Node REPL - raised an issue with Node.js - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11604

Comment: @arcseldon Yes, the repl does not output strings but string literals. Use `console.log(myString)` to get the value printed

Answer (score 14):

Try using [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw):

```js
const name = String.raw`
  ____                 _ 
 |  _ \               (_)
 | |_) | ___ _ __ __ _ _ 
 |  _ < / _ | '__/ _' | |
 | |_) |  __| | | (_| | |
 |____/ \___|_|  \__, |_|
                  __/ |  
                 |___/   
`
```

Comment: Note that your original example didn't work as you used a backtick. You still need to escape two characters with `String.raw` -- the backtick and the dolar sign.

Comment: Hm... Actually you cannot use backtick at all because 
`String.raw\`\\`\` !== '\`'`